# How to reverse engineer a motorcycle speedometer?

Tags: automotive

I hope this is the correct forum for this type of question. 
I'm trying to start a project to figure out and create a replacement for my motor cycle speedometer.

my goal is to take the current unit, understand how it works and then figure out a design for a replacement speedo.

The speedo in question is a digital display with several discreet inputs to set off warning lights.

There are also control buttons to change modes and reset displays.  All inputs are electrical from the wiring harness and possibly one input that is digital from the ECU.

Mostly i am looking for help and advice on how to go about figuring out this problem more than anything.  I am a software engineer but i have never worked on anything remotely like this.

Comment: Step 1, get the wiring diagram for your bike.

Comment: Are you looking to just copy the current speedo using other components or to design and build your own system? If the former, get the diagram and copy away. The latter case is a much more interesting problem.

Comment: A1. Wiring diagram is on the way. A2.  Looking to Design my own system but build from existing aftermarket components or partner with a MFG'r

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, as @Passerby says, get the wiring diagram - factory service manual should have it.

If that (as it might well) leaves some parts unclear,  step 2 would likely involve some sort of datalogger connected to the wires, ideally synchronized with a video feed of the face as you take it out and ride it for a while to generate some data events, followed by sorting out what the data did when various things were done/displayed.

You'd probably want some nice boring runs at various constant speeds to sort out the actual speedometer function - if it's "non-mechanical" in nature it's probably a combination of an engine speed sensor and a gear sensor, though it's just barely possible you have a wheel sensor (the service manual should know that, at least.) If you pull in the clutch and idle while coasting at speed, what does the speedometer do? Plummet with engine speed or reflect actual road speed?

Comment: I know it doesn't have a wheel sensor I think the data comes from the ECU

Answer (score 0):

First research all the chips in the circuit. Carefully follow all the traces in the circuit and draw a schematic. A multimeter using the continuity function will help here. If you can get a multimeter with a low volt ohm function that would be even better, it would keep from turning on any PN junctions. If some of the chips could not be identified then how they connect in the circuit could give away what they are. That's about it but if any components are custom or propriety or require software then you're up a creek without a paddle.

If it was me, I would recommend analyzing the signals coming into and out of the speedometer and create your own circuits to replicate the same functionality. Further, I suspect that the speedometer is broken or is known to break. A redesign may cure what ails it.

Comment: Do you know of a good multimeter I can get complete novice..

Comment: @MB. that is a very loaded question. Price has a lot to do with it. A $5 meter will never do what you want but getting started a $500 will be too much. I would suggest watching the eevblog.com multimeter shoot outs and reviews to get a better understanding of what you might want or need.